# Should Shrinking increase Defensive Roll?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e, defense

[Shrinking](https://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/effects/effect-descriptions/shrinking-general) states

> Add half your Shrinking rank (rounded down) to your active defenses.

[Defensive Roll](https://www.d20herosrd.com/5-advantages#TOC-DEFENSIVE-ROLL-COMBAT-RANKED-) states

> You receive a bonus to your Toughness equal to your advantage rank, but it is considered an active defense similar to Dodge and Parry (see [Active Defenses](https://www.d20herosrd.com/character-creation../3-abilities/#ACTIVE_DEFENSES) in Abilities), so you lose this bonus whenever you are vulnerable or defenseless.

In some places, such as All Out Attack, and Defensive Attack, it explicitly states that the active defenses being affected are Dodge and Parry, but not so in this case. So, should Shrinking also increase your Defensive Roll (keeping within PL, of course)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No.

Defensive Roll provides a bonus equal to **Advantage Rank**. Shrinking does not increase your ranks in any Advantage.

---

Separately, if Shrinking added half-ranks to both Dodge/Parry *and* Toughness (via Defensive Roll) then it would hit PL caps very quickly (12 ranks becomes +6 PL). 4 PP of Shrinking becomes 3 PP of Dodge + Parry + Toughness and 2 PP of Stealth, making it exceedingly efficient before power modifiers.

Comment: I'm going to give this another day or so, but you definitely have the only answer so far. :-D I may also ask Steve Kenson on M&M Monday, see what he says.